# Notarize issue: altool not in PATH?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-builder, notarize

**OSX version: 10.14.6**
**electron-builder: 22.11.1**
**electron-notarize: 1.0.0**

I've been trying to `notarize` an `Electron` app using the latest version of [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/), however I keep getting the error:

> error: unable to find utility "altool", not a developer tool or in
> PATH

I've seen the other questions related to this issue and based on the suggestions, I've removed, reinstalled and selected the CommandLineTools using:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools   
xcode-select --install   
sudo xcode-select -r
```

Check the path:

```
xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

This is in the 'Library' directory at the root level of the drive, not the "user" account "Library" directory. So that's all good (I guess) but I still get the above error. Also, if I look in the directory `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` I do not see this "altool". Is it somewhere else?

Am I doing something obviously wrong? If I output the PATH (below) I don't see any reference to the CommandLineTools directory. Is it odd that the installer pkg did not do that?

I'm hesitant to "try anything" but I am getting to that point. What can I try next?

> echo "$PATH"
> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin

Comment: Could you include in the question your version of Xcode? Are you running the latest version?

Comment: I am not using Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Xcode – the command line tools do not include altool, but Xcode does.

Assuming you install Xcode to `/Applications` you will find `altool` at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/altool
```

So you could edit your `~/.bashrc` to update the path:

```bash
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/:$PATH"
```